# Can I use an iMac as monitor for MacBook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, imac

Is this possible with an early 2009 iMac without Thunderbolt and a 2011 MacBook Pro?

My dream solution looks like a [Apple Thunderbolt Display](http://www.apple.com/displays/)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No**, as the first iMac which allows this is the **27-inch Late 2009 iMac**, as explained [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3924).

There are, though, some Applications which may achieve something *similar*, requiring both computers to be connected to the same *LAN/WiFi/VPN*, and sending all the information, the one to be displayed on the second computer working as a display, through it. Such as [ScreenRecycler](http://www.screenrecycler.com/help.html). You can find some more [here](http://mac.appstorm.net/roundups/utilities-roundups/30-apps-for-your-multiple-monitor-setup/).

Comment: Ic accept the answer, but I didn't try the software solutions! I think I'll buy a new screen and a docking station!

Answer (score -1):

Yeah, you actually can. Check out a program called Screen Recycler. It costs money, but the trial will work for long enough.

Also, check out air server and air parrot. If you run air parrot on the macbook, and connect to the iMac with air server, it will also work.